# Remove vertical scrollbar on fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove vertical scrollbar after switch to fullscreen.

This is the script I'm using at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
} else {
    $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
}
</script>
```

I've tried like this without any success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.fullScreen) {
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
} else {
    $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
}
</script>
```

Tank you as always.

EDIT:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` is being loaded and other jquery script's are working ok.

EDIT:
I've tested with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

And it works!
So I believe that for some reason the JavaScript condition code it's not working!
`if((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height))`...

EDIT:

Solution found!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var control = 0;

function scrollbar(){
    if(event.keyCode == 122 && control == 0){
        //remove scrollbar
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        control = 1;
    }
    else{
        //add scrollbar
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        control = 0;
    }
}

</script>
```

If you want to use this don't forget to attach the function to the body for example like:

```
<body onkeydown="scrollbar();">
```

UPDATE:

Work's in chrome, opera, ie, safari except for firefox! What can be done to fix firefox?

Comment: I suggest `$("body").css("overflow","hidden")`, or make a div wraps everything and use `overflow` property.

Comment: I've tried also $("body").css("overflow","hidden") without any success either...

Comment: In fullscreen I don't need scrollbar.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this script will execute once the page loads.  And if it is not loading full screen, then you will likely not get the desired results.  You probably need to attach a click event to the F11 key.

Comment: That make all sense! Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the javascript is only being run once, when the document loads, and not re-evaluate afterwards. If this is the only problem, you should see the correct behaviour if you are in full screen then load the page. To fix this you will have to make a function out of your code and call it every time the window is resized. Using jQuery, you can do this using an anonymous function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function() {
    if((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {
        $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    } else {
        $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
    // trigger the function when the page loads
    // if you have another $(document).ready(), simply add this line to it
});
</script>
```

This binds the function to the resize event handler and you should see correct results! If that works it will be a *much* nicer and robust way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a LOT BudgieInWA your solution works just perfect! Please add ");" at the end...

Comment: BudgieInWA. Well while I press F11 the window resizes as expected but, when in fullscreen mode if click any link of the menu the scrollbar comes up again! How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @FCC-PT, I have edited in the code to trigger the resize event handler when the docuement is loaded.